# Why do I see this error "Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action."?

Tags: python, binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to access a binance api that requires a client's signature. I use the python code from this binance FAQ(https://dev.binance.vision/t/why-do-i-see-this-error-invalid-api-key-ip-or-permissions-for-action/93/1) for this:
https://github.com/binance/binance-signature-examples/blob/master/python/futures/um_futures.py

Here is my key permissions: [image]

The keys are copied correctly, the IP address is added correctly. The key is created after creating a futures account. Why am I getting a response:

```
{'code': -2015, 'msg': 'Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action, request ip: ...'}
```

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

import cred

KEY = cred.KEY
SECRET = cred.SECRET
BASE_URL = "https://fapi.binance.com"  # production base url
# BASE_URL = "https://testnet.binancefuture.com"  # testnet base url


def hashing(query_string):
    return hmac.new(
        SECRET.encode("utf-8"), query_string.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()


def get_timestamp():
    return int(time.time() * 1000)


def dispatch_request(http_method):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(
        {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8", "X-MBX-APIKEY": KEY}
    )
    return {
        "GET": session.get,
        "DELETE": session.delete,
        "PUT": session.put,
        "POST": session.post,
    }.get(http_method, "GET")


# used for sending request requires the signature
def send_signed_request(http_method, url_path, payload={}):
    query_string = urlencode(payload)
    # replace single quote to double quote
    query_string = query_string.replace("%27", "%22")
    if query_string:
        query_string = "{}&timestamp={}".format(query_string, get_timestamp())
    else:
        query_string = "timestamp={}".format(get_timestamp())

    url = (
        BASE_URL + url_path + "?" + query_string + "&signature=" + hashing(query_string)
    )
    print("{} {}".format(http_method, url))
    params = {"url": url, "params": {}}
    response = dispatch_request(http_method)(**params)
    return response.json()


# get account informtion
# if you can see the account details, then the API key/secret is correct
response = send_signed_request("GET", "/fapi/v2/account")
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I still didn’t open a futures account and didn’t start money on it